# Making a dot density map with tmap package

Tags: dot, tmap

I am trying to make a map using the tmap package, but i don't know the code to do a dot density map. The dataset i have consists of births, and i want to plot the number of births on each region of my map as dots (regions with higher number of births would have higher number of dots). I am not sure if tmap has a function like this, I only know tm_bubble. The map would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it in `tmap`. You can try other packages: https://blog.cultureofinsight.com/2017/06/building-dot-density-maps-with-uk-census-data-in-r/

Comment: Is there a way to plot 2D density with tmap package?

Comment: Hi, I don't think so. But I did it with ggplot!